# Joined MSSQL Tables are not editable in QGIS?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join two tables (MSSQL tables) in QGIS and then match some fields and insert/update them.

However, when I join two tables from DB Manager and show them as a new layer, I cannot edit any data.

Does anyone know why I can't edit, and how to make it editable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how you're joining tables in QGIS as DB Manager doesn't work with MSSQL tables...

Otherwise, you can't edit data in joins nor can you edit data in views, so you might have to come up with a new workflow...